# Getting points inside selected feature in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-location

I have incorporated district map of India and excel table contents(which consist latitude, longitude and fire data)using add data feature in ArcGIS Desktop.

I have attached the picture below to show what I got after this. 
Then I selected 1 district (It is India's map, blocks which you can see are representing different districts). It can be seen in the picture attached as a polygon : outer lining is of sea-green colour.

How do I get all the data points that lie inside the selected district in a table format?

When I am selecting that particular district, I can only get information about the few points and is time consuming.

[image]

[image: I have attached the picture to show the points I am interested in knowing which lie inside the layer file]

Comment: Join data from another layer based on spatial location and sort it by polygons field.

Answer (score 1):

The tool to do this is [Select Layer By Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm) which:

> Selects features in a layer based on a spatial relationship to
>   features in another layer.
>
> Each feature in the **Input Feature Layer** is evaluated against the
>   features in the **Selecting Features** layer or feature class; if the
>   specified **Relationship** is met, the input feature is selected.

Once you have selected the points using the above tool you can Open their Attribute Table by right-clicking on that layer in the Table of Contents.

Select By Location is also available from ArcMap's Main Menu under Selection.  The Help page on [Steps for using Select By Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) explains how to use it from there.

Comment: I can only use this function if one of the fields are same in both the layers selected right? But problem is I just have latitude, longitude values and points overlapping shapefile representing fire data. The shapefile had its own object ID,  district name, state name etc. But no fields are common in both. Hence, it is difficult to know the points existing inside the shapefile (which I have now converted to layer file).

Comment: I have added a picture above showing a layer file. What could be the way to know what all points lie inside it in one go?

Comment: You commented that "I can only use this function if one of the fields are same in both the layers selected right?".  Your comment is wrong. Select By Location uses feature locations only and NOT feature attribute values to perform its selection.